# How are these wires connected (see picture)?

Tags: wire-terminals, crimp, power-connector

I'm trying to replace the timer component in a toaster oven I have. I am not very knowledgeable about different connector/terminal types, so I thought I'd confirm with more experienced people here.

It looks to me like these are small female spade connectors connected to large male spade connectors. It doesn't look like there is any solder here (I even tried with a soldering iron with no result), and I see pliers marks. Could these just be glued together? If so, how safe is that (these carry 120V and toaster body is all metal)? Any other theories?

My goal is to replace the part with the male connectors. If these are glued together, it would seem like the best option would be to remove the female crimp connectors and use new, appropriately sized ones. Does that sound right?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like spot welding.

Comment: Thanks! That does make sense (more than glue for sure :)). I guess it doesn't change the resolution of needing new terminals, though.

Comment: The terminals on the device (switch?) look like they would mate with 1/4" Faston(tm) terminals.